# Select a distinct list of words from an array with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I'm trying to get a distinct list of words from an array of words with the following code:

```
string words = "this is a this b";

var split = words.Split(' ');

IEnumerable<Word> distinctWords = (
    from w in split
    select new Word
    {
        Text = w.ToString()
    }
    ).Distinct().ToList();
```

I thought this would take out the double occurrence of 'this' but it returns a list of each word in the phrase.

Comment: Shouldn't the 2nd line be `string[] split = words.Split()`?

Comment: D'Oh! - @Mark, you're right. I guess I got a bit sloppy with my copy/paste - I've fixed it now. I'd had one or two glasses at that stage though! :-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In your example, each Word object *is* distinct, because there is no comparison which looks at the Text property.

However, there's no reason to create a new object:

```
var distinctWords = (from w in split 
                      select w).Distinct().ToList();
```

Or more simply:

```
var distinctWords = new List<string>(split.Distinct());
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted the code for your `Word` class, but my guess is that it doesn't implement `Equals` with a value comparison so you get the default implementation of `Equals` which just checks the object references. Note that if you decide to implement your own version of `Equals`, you also need to correctly implement `GetHashCode`.

An alternative way to solve this issue is to provide an `IEqualityComparer` as a parameter to the `Distinct` function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you create several Word objects that contain the same Value, but how should the compiler know, that these shall be the same items?

Try

```
(from w in split.Distinct()
select new Word { Text = w.ToString()}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to convert array ToList() first before calling the .Distinct()
and then converting it ToArray() again

```
myArray= myArray.ToList().Distinct().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

As others noted, the problem is probably that your `Word` object doesn't implement structural equality (compare the actual content, not instance references). If you still want to get a collection of `Word` objects as the result, but use `Distinct` on the underlying string values, you can write this:

```
IEnumerable<Word> distinctWords = 
   (from w in split.Distinct() 
    select new Word { Text = w.ToString() }).ToList();
```